# How to build a static library for both iPhone OS 3 and OS 4?

Tags: iphone, static-libraries, ios4

I created a .a lib file and it was built under iPhone OS 3.0 (in XCode 3.2.2). Now I found that it doesn't work on OS 4. I was using the lipo command to build the .a file for both simulator version and device version:

```
lipo -create libdevice.a libsimulator.a -output libcombined.a
```

Now I created another .a file under iPhone OS 4.0 (in XCode 3.2.3). My question is that is it possible to combine the two lib files together? (libcombined3.a and libcombined4.a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the 4.0 version will work on 3.0, you don't need the 3.0 specific version anymore. Move completely over to iOS4.

Comment: Are u sure? I use the os4.a for 3.0 specific project and get dozens of reference error.

Comment: Yes, just update the code to compile against 4.0, set its base SDK to 4, and its deploy target to 3.0 or whatnot. Of course test it on device to make sure it still works.

Comment: Thx. And one more question: I find that the os4combined version(built with os4device.a os4simu.a) doesn't work for os3 simulator (works fine on the device).

Comment: I mean simulator 3.0 to 3.1.3, exclude 3.2

Comment: I created a .a lib which combines the lib for both the os4 device and the os4 simulator. When I add it to a project in os3 simulator mode and build the whole app, a reference error will be reported.

Comment: This doesn't matter much, though.